# MouseOverEvent in FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to create a mouseoverevent in full calendar in JQuery.

The problem in my code is when I take mouse over an event it displays title but not staff and location. I have looked online but didn't get the exact answer I am looking for.

I was thinking of calling an external function to get location and staff value which is coming as undefined. Is that even achievable?

```
function getFilterParams(start, end) {
  var selectedLocations = [];
  $('#SelectedLocation option:selected').each(function (index, opt) {
    selectedLocations.push(opt.value);
  });
  var selectedAssets = [];
  $('#SelectedObjects option:selected').each(function (index, opt) {
    selectedAssets.push(opt.value);
  });

  var selectedStaff = [];   
  $('#SelectedStaff option:selected').each(function (index, opt) {
    selectedStaff.push(opt.value);
  });
  var selectedVendor = [];
  $('#SelectedVendor option:selected').each(function (index, opt) {
    selectedVendor.push(opt.value);
  });
  var filterParams = {
    startDateUnix: start.unix(),
    endDateUnix: end.unix(),
    AssetList: selectedAssets, 
    StaffList: selectedStaff,
    VendorList: selectedVendor,
    LocationList: selectedLocations,
  };
  return filterParams;
  }
  $('#WorkOrderCalendar').fullCalendar({
      header: {
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
      },
      defaultView: 'month',
      lang: '@_Calendar_lang_code',
      editable: true,
      eventLimit: true,
      SlotMinutes: 15,
      eventSources:
      [
          var jqCalendarParams = getFilterParams(start, end);

          $.ajax({
          url: '@urlGetEventList',
          dataType: "json",
          type: "POST",
          aspectRatio: 2,
          cache: false,
          traditional: true,
          data: jqCalendarParams,
          success: function(result) {
              var events = [];
              for (var c = 0; c < (result.events).length; c++) {
                  events.push({
                      id: result.events[c].id,
                      title: result.events[c].title,
                      url: result.events[c].url,
                      staff: result.events[c].staff,
                      location: result.events[c].location
                  });
              }
          })
      ],
      eventMouseover: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
          var wotitle = calEvent.title;
          var wostaff = calEvent.staff;
          var wolocation = calEvent.location;
              var tooltip = '<div class="tooltipevent" style="width:120px;height:100px;background:gray;position:absolute;z-index:10001;white-space: pre-wrap;">' + wotitle + '\n' + wostaff + '\n' + wolocation + '</div>';
              var $tooltip = $(tooltip).appendTo('body');
              (this).mouseover(function (e) {
                  $(this).css('z-index', 10000);
                  $tooltip.fadeIn('500');
                  $tooltip.fadeTo('10', 1.9);
              }).mousemove(function (e) {
                  $tooltip.css('top', e.pageY + 10);
                  $tooltip.css('left', e.pageX + 20);
              );
          },
          calEvent.url = "";
          return false;
      },
      eventMouseout: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
          $(this).css('z-index', 8);
          $('.tooltipevent').remove();
      },
      loading: function (bool) {
          if (bool)
              $('.loadingInProgress').show();
          else
              $('.loadingInProgress').hide();
      }
  });
```

Comment: Can you share an example of the JSON that is returned from your `ajax`?

Comment: are you getting values in variables `wostaff` & `wolocation` ? Please check it once. Better to check the json response if it is returning all the values you require.

Comment: Verify you are getting data from calEvent or not which you are expecting